# Dynamic drop down from text file one by one

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Load drop down one by one, when i select first drop down i can load second drop down and when i select second drop down and the third has to load but failed

My code:

**HTML**

```
                   <label>Select Category <span>*</span></label>
                    <select id="cateabc" class="">
                        <option>Select Category</option>
                        <option value="Mobile">Mobiles</option>
                        </select>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <label >Select Sub Category <span>*</span></label>
                    <select id="text-two" style="display :none">
                        <option>Please choose from above</option>
                    </select>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <label >Mobile Brand <span>*</span></label>
                    <select id="text-three" style="display :none">
                        <option>Please choose from above</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

**Script:**

```
$(function () {
                $("#cateabc").change(function () {
                    $("#text-two").show();
                    $("#text-two").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
                });
            });
            $(function () {
                $("#text-two").change(function () {
                    $("#text-three").show();
                    $("#text-three").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
                });
            });
```

**Mobile.txt**

```
<option value="Mobile Phone">Mobile Phone</option>
<option value="Tablet">Tablet</option>
<option value="Accessories">Accessories</option>
```

**Mobile Phone.txt**

```
<option value="Nokia">Nokia</option>
<option value="aple">apple</option>
<option value="sony">sony</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode your **URL** while making **AJAX** requests using `encodeURIComponent` as a presence of space might be breaking this functionality.

**Code:**

```
$("#text-two").change(function () {
    $("#text-three").show();
    var url = "textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt";
    url = encodeURIComponent(url);
    $("#text-three").load(url);
});
```

Comment: doesnt work when i select second drop down third has o response

Comment: @sanojlawrence yea.. try doing `encodeURIComponent `?

Comment: is there a way to do the same with '<lable>'

Comment: drop down label how could i display once selected